# Stop clicking on text from cancelling selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection, contenteditable

I'm trying to make a simple rich text editor, and I'm getting stuck at the stupidest thing. For the bold buttons, instead of having a button, I'm trying to make it so that, near the top of the screen, there are several spans, and each one has a thing you can do to the text, such as `bold`, `italic`, `underline`, etc, and when you click on one I want it to toggle if the selected text in the `contenteditable` div is bold, italic, or underline. Basically, instead of buttons, I want to simply click on a span to toggle those things.

So I put a whole bunch of spans in the right place and put event handlers on them that did the appropriate `execCommand`. However, when the user clicks on the spans, it cancels the selection in the `contenteditable` div, so that the execCommand doesn't do anything. I tried setting the css `user-select` to `none` (I also used prefixes), cancelling the `selectstart` event, cancelling the `click` event, but it still cancels the selection when I click on it

You can see the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/28rmK/1/)

I don't want to use a button instead of a span or anything. I don't want to do it in a hacky way (such as copying the selection on input, and then recreating the selection after the click) either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few ways to achieve this. You can prevent the default `mousedown` behaviour like below:

```
document.getElementById('bold').addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/28rmK/2/)

You can also just use the semantically correct elements such as `<button>` rather than `<span>`. If you do not like the way `<button>` element looks by default just re-style it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/28rmK/3/)